# "make target" not working after "make clean"

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to write a Makefile for a small C program. It's structure is

project_root

- src (source files)
- tests (test files)
- build (program binary)

My make file is below.

```
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -Isrc $(OPTFLAGS)
LDLIBS = $(OPTLIBS)

PREFIX ?= /usr/local/
OPTVALGRIND="valgrind --track-origins=yes --log-file=tests/valgrind.log"

TARGET_SRC = src/hello_make.c
TARGET = build/hello_make

SOURCES := $(wildcard src/*.c)
SOURCES := $(filter-out $(TARGET_SRC),$(SOURCES))

OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SOURCES))

TEST_SRC = $(wildcard tests/*_tests.c)
TESTS = $(patsubst %.c,%,$(TEST_SRC))
TEST_FILE ?= hello_make_tests

all: $(TARGET) tests

$(TARGET): build $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(TARGET_SRC) $(OBJECTS) $(LDLIBS) -o $@ 

.PHONY: compile_tests tests test testv valgrind build clean
compile_tests: LDLIBS += -lrt -lm
compile_tests: CFLAGS += $(OBJECTS)
compile_tests: build $(OBJECTS) $(TESTS)
    @echo "TARGET=$(TARGET), TESTS=$(TESTS)"
    @echo "compile_tests done"

tests: compile_tests
    sh ./tests/run_tests.sh

test: compile_tests
    sh ./tests/run_test.sh tests/$(TEST_FILE)

testv: compile_tests
    sh ./tests/run_test.sh tests/$(TEST_FILE)

valgrind:
    VALGRIND=$(OPTVALGRIND) $(MAKE) -s

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJECTS)
    rm -rf $(TARGET)
    rm -rf $(TESTS)
    rm -rf build
    rm -rf tests/*.log

build:
    @mkdir -p build
```

I have a target test and testv(corresponding for running with valgrind).
So when I do,

```
make test TEST_FILE=hello_make_tests
```

it should build anything needed for this test. Then run tests/hello_make_tests.

I have most of the Makefile working. It builds and compiles the source files to .o
links those to the test program.
$\

> My problem is that this only works if I use **make all** first then followed by **make test**.
>   When I do **make clean** followed by **make test**. I get the following error.

```
cc -g -Wall -Isrc  src/get_one.o src/get_three.o src/get_two.o   -c -o src/get_one.o src/get_one.c
cc: error: src/get_one.o: No such file or directory
cc: error: src/get_three.o: No such file or directory
cc: error: src/get_two.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [src/get_one.o] Error 1
```

> The cc call seems to be wrong with object files acting as sources? I am pretty new to make and am
>   unable to figure this out. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
compile_tests: CFLAGS += $(OBJECTS)
```

adds all objects to the CFLAGS variable which will be used by the implicit rules (that are built into make) when compiling.

Try to keep source, compiler flags and resulting object files separate in your makefile to avoid this kind of confusion.

Have a quick look at the documentation for the makefile flags if you're uncertain of their usage.

Comment: Thanks. I only added that line because it doesn't link src files with the test file...

Comment: @mathguy80 You're welcome. Did this solve your problem or is there more information to add to your question?

Comment: Yes it did, thanks. The Make manual is pretty well written. I ended up writing an implicit rule for $(TESTS) which does $(CC) $(OBJECTS) $@.c -o $@.

Comment: @mathguy80 Yes, there is lots to be gained from reading it a couple of times just to get a feeling for all the functionality that has been added. When your project grows, you'll thank your former self for using the clever bits effectively.